# Find max value in a group of subsublists in a specific order

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

```
L=[
[ [4.0, 4.0] , [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] ],
[ [4.0, 5.0] , [1.0          ] ]
]
```

I need to get the max value of each 'column' of sublists. In other words I must get:

```
result=[5.0, 3.0]
```

...because `5.0` is the max value in the first 'column' of subsublists:

```
[4.0, 4.0]
[4.0, 5.0]
```

...and `3.0` is the max value in second columns of subsublists:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
[1.0]
```

**Number of sublists may change, as well as number of subsublists and values inside subsublists**, I'm afraid. I've been trying for hours but I'm just able to iterate in the first value of subsublists, therefore I'm missing the max values located at the end of their respective subsublists :-( Thank you in advance.

*PS.: Unfortuntately I cannot use Pandas or Numpy...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip`

```
L= [[[4.0, 4.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]], [[4.0, 5.0], [1.0]]]
new_l = [max(c for b in i for c in b) for i in zip(*L)]
```

Output:

```
[5.0, 3.0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @Ajax1234 it works perfectly! Thank you!!

Comment: @Victor This solution won't work if the numbers of subsublists are not equal.

Comment: @liliscent thank you very much for the advise, I'm currently doing some tests in my program. Apparently it's working fine even with different number of subsublists inside a sublist... not sure if that's because i'm filling up with zeros afterwards in case of asymetric sublists... but I'll definitely will keep trying out, this one and yours as well. **THANK YOU!!** You guys are lifesavers!

Comment: @Victor Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
In [140]: import itertools as it

In [141]: [max(max(g) for g in e if g) for e in it.zip_longest(*L)]
Out[141]: [5.0, 3.0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!! I'll try to keep itertools in mind for the next one! Thank you!! @liliscent

Answer (score 0):

Ugly solution using `functools.partial`:

```
list(map(max, zip(*map(partial(map, max), L))))
# [5.0, 3.0]
```

Here, `map(partial(map, max), L)` transforms each row by picking the maximum of each cell; `zip` performs the transpose; another `map(max, ...)` finds the maximum of each column.

Less ugly solution:

```
c1 = c2 = 0
for col1, col2 in L:
    c1 = max(c1, *col1)
    c2 = max(c2, *col2)
# c1 = 5; c2 = 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @Yakym Pirozhenko I love this solution as well. Thanks!!